# My nav bar is going over text and the li's aren't even on the nav bar

Tags: html, css

I'm making a webpage, just kind of for fun, but the problem is the nav bar. It either goes over the paragraph text, or under it. Also, the navigation links (Home, About, Resources, and Contact) are hiding underneath the nav bar. Here is a bit of code:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

#header h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: 3em;
  color: #50E3C2;
  font-size: 36px;
} 

#header ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#header ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: both;
}

#header li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #ccc;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

And here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cY22L/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#body {
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

That should do it fine :)

Answer (score 0):

to get your bar right displayed you have to set h1 floaf:left because it pushes the rest of the bar

```
h1{
    float:left;
}
```

the content needs a margin as high as the header. see other post

Answer (score 0):

I updated your js fiddle, and i think this is how you were trying to get it to work... take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/cY22L/4/

compare the 2 different css texts to see the changes. here is the new css:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
}
#header {
width:100%;
position: fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ccc;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
z-index:5;
}
#header h1 {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
margin-left: 3em;
color: #50E3C2;
font-size: 36px;
}
#header ul {
float: right;
margin-right: 10px;
}
#header ul li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
clear: both;
}
#header li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
color: #ccc;
padding-right: 15px;
float: left;
}
p {
font-size: 24px;
}
#body
{
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:150px;
}
```